# Two QListView box one showing files in a folder and one shows selected files from the first QListview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hlay = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.listview = QListView()
        self.listview2 = QListView()

        hlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview2)

        path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project'

        self.fileModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)

        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to display the files in my listview from my folder with path described in the code and able to
select them, the files I selected will be displayed in my listview2, However, the listview doesn't show 
the files in this path. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Do you want that when a file is selected then it is added to the other QListView or only what is selected is shown?

Comment: Are you asking me ?, I have not yet pointed out a solution so I do not understand your question. I still have doubts about what you want, for example let's say that 5 files of 100 have been selected and they are in the second QListView, and let's say that one of those 5 files is deselected. Should that same item be eliminated in the second QListView? if not, how would an item in the second QListView be deleted?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes exactly what you said, when you select files, selected files appear in the second QListView and when you deselect, deselected ones will disappear from the second QListView

Comment: Now it's clearer, what information other than the name of the file do you want the second QListView to have?

Comment: You say: *By now I just want the files*, a file are many things: the name of the file, the path of the file, the weight of the file, the date of creation, date of modification, etc., what do you want it to be? show in the second QListView? What do you think about using the information contained in the second QListView?

Comment: just the filenames, I am trying to run this files I selected in python to see if they have exit code 0 or 1, so perhaps I will put a pushbutton at the bottom and when i click the button, python will run this files to check if they run successfully or not.

Comment: okay, now what color does it depend on?, that is, if I had n-files as they would be the colors of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are not displayed because you have not set a `rootPath` in the `QFileSystemModel`.

On the other hand the second `QListView` must have a model where items are added or removed as they are selected or deselected, for this you must use the `selectionChanged` signal of `selectionModel()` of the first `QListView`, that signal transports the information of the selected and deselected items.

To change the color you must obtain the `QStandardItem` and use the `setData()` method with the `Qt::BackgroundRole` role. In the example in each second the color is changed randomly

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listview2 = QtWidgets.QListView()

        path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Project'

        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.fileModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))
        self.listview.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.on_selectionChanged)
        self.listview.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.listview2.setModel(self.model)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview2)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.test_color)
        timer.start()

    def on_selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        roles = (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, 
                 QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole,
                 QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole,
                 QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)

        for ix in selected.indexes():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(ix.data())
            for role in roles:
                it.setData(ix.data(role), role)
            it.setData(QtGui.QColor("green"), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
            self.model.appendRow(it)

        filter_role = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole
        for ix in deselected.indexes():
            for index in self.model.match(ix.parent(), filter_role, ix.data(filter_role), -1, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly):
                self.model.removeRow(index.row())

    def test_color(self):
        if self.model.rowCount() > 0:
            n_e = random.randint(0, self.model.rowCount())
            rows_red = random.sample(range(self.model.rowCount()), n_e)
            for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                it = self.model.item(row)
                if row in rows_red:
                    it.setData(QtGui.QColor("red"), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
                else:
                    it.setData(QtGui.QColor("green"), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! just one quick question, the `ix in selected.indexes()` are `PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object`, how do I retreive the file name of the ix

Comment: @Cindy use `ix.data()` or `ix.data(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FilePathRole)` or `ix.data(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)`